# malfunction of tf.device() on Windows

Tags: python, tensorflow

tf.device('/gpu:0') fail to run the model on only gpu0, other gpus will be occupied as well. As a result, all the memory of all gpu cards on my server are filled. By setting 'config.gpu_options.visible_device_list = "0"', the model will run on gpu0 only.

BTW, only the memory of other gpus are filled, no actual computation is performed on them, all the computation is performed on gpu0.

Anyone who can tell me what's going on is sincerely appreciated.

**Environment info**

Operating System: Windows Server 2012 R2
CUDA: 8.0
NO cuDNN

**A link to the pip package you installed:**

using 'pip install tensorflow-gpu' to install

**The output from python -c "import tensorflow; print(tensorflow.__version__)".**

1.0.1

**What other attempted solutions have you tried?**

config = tf.ConfigProto()

config.gpu_options.visible_device_list = '0'

using 'config' to open a session, the graph will only run on '/gpu:0';

Comment: Can you try setting the `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` environment to `0` before starting Python and see if that works?

Comment: It's not a "malfunction on windows" - regardless of what exist where on the graph, TF will grab all the memory it sees on the graphics cards.

Comment: But I set tf.device('/gpu:0'), it should only grab the memory of gpu:0, not all the cards', am I right?